# Unable to Create Space Between Font Awesome Icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to get some space between my 4 `fa-icons` to spread them out more across the page. I'd like them to take up around **75%** of the page. The `HTML` and accompanying `CSS` is shown below:

```css
.fa-icons {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-background-face {
  color: #3b5998;
}
.fa-facebook {
  color: #fff;
}
.facebook i {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.icon-background-twit {
  color: #00aced;
}
.fa-twitter {
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-background-tube {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.fa-youtube {
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-background-env {
  color: #000000;
}
.fa-envelope {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="fa-icons">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">"
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-face fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-twit fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-tube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-env"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin` like this:

```
.fa-stack {
    margin-right: 10px; <-- change accordingly
}
```

Create a custom class name for the last div and add `margin-right: 0;` to prevent unwanted margin after that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add margin to the `fa`s, see the following example:

```css
.fa-icons {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-icons span {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.icon-background-face {
  color: #3b5998;
}
.fa-facebook {
  color: #fff;
}
.facebook i {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.icon-background-twit {
  color: #00aced;
}
.fa-twitter {
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-background-tube {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.fa-youtube {
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-background-env {
  color: #000000;
}
.fa-envelope {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="fa-icons">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">"
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-face fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-twit fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-tube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-env"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Both these solutions work, but it results in the icons stacking 1 on top of each other when shrunk to mobile view.

Is it possible to get them to stack 2 on 2 when shrinking the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course, you need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), this way you can reset margins to `zero` on narrower screens

Answer (score 0):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/bulentv/pen/NdeRxd?editors=1100)

```css
.fa-icons {
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.fa-icons>span{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}


.icon-background-face {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-background-twit {
  color: #00aced;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-background-tube {
  color: #bb0000;
}

.fa-youtube {
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-background-env {
  color: #000000;
}

.fa-envelope {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="fa-icons">

  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-face fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-twit fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x fa-stack-1x fa-fw"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-tube"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <a href="">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background-env"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```